# How do you access a Google Sheet with a service account from Java?

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to access a Google Sheet from a service account (the service account has access to the sheet). But I have a problem, all the documentation including the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) point to use `GoogleCredential` that is deprecated since 1.7. The deprecation says that you sould use library `google-auth-library` and this is what I'm doing in:

```scala
val googleCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials
      .fromStream(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH))
      .createScoped(SCOPES)
googleCredentials.refresh()
```

but the variable is of type `GoogleCredentials` and the function `Sheets.Builder` doesn't accept this as a valid `HttpRequestInitializer`. So I had to hack my way around using the deprecated class with:

```scala
val token = googleCredentials.getAccessToken.getTokenValue
val credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token)
```

With this workaround I'm able to access the Google Sheet but I'm sure that there is a proper way to do it without using deprecated libraries.

Does anyone know what's the proper way to do it?

Leaving here the full snippet as a reference.

```scala
package drivers
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Collections

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.{Sheets, SheetsScopes}
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

object TestDriver {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val config = ConfigFactory.load()
    val spreadsheetId = config.getString("spreadsheetId")
    val CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = config.getString("google_application_credentials")

    val SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY)
    val JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance
    val APPLICATION_NAME = "my-app"

    val googleCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials
      .fromStream(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH))
      .createScoped(SCOPES)
    googleCredentials.refresh()

    val token = googleCredentials.getAccessToken.getTokenValue
    val credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(token)
    val httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport
    val service = new Sheets.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
      .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
      .build()
    val range = "Sheet1!A1:D1"
    val response = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId, range).execute()
    val values = response.getValues
    values.forEach(println)
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The information is confusing, the [Google Auth Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java) that is [recommended to use](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-java-client/commit/45825c4157eee2a7254817b1aae9aa63ba726726) since the deprecation includes the `google-auth-library-oauth2` library
- In other words, you can still use `GoogleCredential`, and it is still the method recommended in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests):

```java
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH))
    .createScoped(Collections.singleton(SCOPES));
```

- Alternatively, you can also build your credential from a .p12 file:

```java
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(httpTransport)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(emailAddress)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("MyProject.p12"))
    .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton(YOUR SCOPE))
    .build();
```

- However, if you do want to use `GoogleCredentials` and have problems with the `HttpRequestInitializer` you can use the [HttpCredentialsAdapter](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/master/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/http/HttpCredentialsAdapter.java)

Comment: Thanks I went the `HttpCredentialsAdapter` and works like a charm. Since I guess this will be the way to go in the future I'll keep that.

Comment: Works. Here is how you use `HttpCredentialsAdapter` in a spring bean:
---
@Bean
    fun getGoogCreds(creds: GoogleCredentials): HttpCredentialsAdapter {
        return HttpCredentialsAdapter(creds)
    }