# Authenticate with a Service Account for Google Sheets API with Java

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I started with the Google Quick Start guide for Java for connecting to Google Sheets via their API (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java). I am following their quick start tutorial as it is without any changes. However, instead of creating an OAuth client ID and downloading that JSON credentials file, I created a Service Account (because that's what it's going to be). However, the downloaded service account JSON file does not work with Google's Quick Start code :

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.ValueRange;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SheetsQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = SheetsQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    /**
     * Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
     * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        final String spreadsheetId = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms";
        final String range = "Class Data!A2:E";
        Sheets service = new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
        ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Name, Major");
            for (List row : values) {
                // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                System.out.printf("%s, %s\n", row.get(0), row.get(4));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and it gives this exception:

> Task :run FAILED
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:131)
> at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:35)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets.getDetails(GoogleClientSecrets.java:80)
> at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow$Builder.(GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.java:211)
> at SheetsQuickstart.getCredentials(SheetsQuickstart.java:50)
> at SheetsQuickstart.main(SheetsQuickstart.java:68)

I have already given 'Edit' access to the service account email id given in the json file to my Google spreadsheet, but it still gives the same error (in fact I tried changing my file permissions to 'anyone with link' can edit, and have used the same google spreadsheet ID in the code). Some webpages suggested a deprecated `GoogleCredential` based solution. Is there a non-deprecated solution to the problem?

Comment: Have you checked on the OAuth 2.0 Java for [Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#service_accounts)?

Comment: Yes, I did after seeing similar messages on several webpages (even though as I wrote it uses the deprecated GoogleCredential class), but even that gave a huge callstack of error (starting with "Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target")

Comment: Unless you're using [Google Workspace Domain-wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation), you **cannot** use a Service Account to access Google Sheets because Sheets provides access to user data. Google requires that services accessing user data must use user credentials via an OAuth2 client **or** use the aforementioned DWDoA

Comment: @DazWilkin I'm not accessing any user data, the service account will just read and write data in a single spreadsheet, to which 'Edit' access has been given to it. So I don't know if Domain wide delegation should be required. Can someone please confirm if I still need it?

Comment: Can you share the code used and the error when you used the [Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#service_accounts)?

Comment: @Kessy : Both are given in the description. I used the exact same code as given in Google's quick start guide for accessing sheets through Java.

Comment: Have you tested the code shared on the first comment [OAuth 2.0 Java for Service accounts](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#service_accounts) in your script and also, have you checked the answer on [How do you access a Google Sheet with a service account from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64135720/how-do-you-access-a-google-sheet-with-a-service-account-from-java)?